# Get the current page URL in Ruby/Rack

Tags: ruby, rack

I can't seem to find an answer to what should be simple. I'm using [Serve](http://get-serve.com/), which runs on a WEBRick server. I'd like to be able to grab the current page's URL. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Serve uses [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) under the hood, try this in a view:

```
<%= request.url %>
```

Comment: Assuming Serve allows access to Rack requests in the views, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for getting the **URI** of the request, following will work:

```
request.path
```